# how to re-order polynomial term factors from sage output

Tags: format, latex, sage

I have

```
 x,y, dx, dy= var("x, y, dx, dy");
 def iD(f): return diff(f, x)*dx + diff(f,y)*dy;
```

`iD(x^3*y^5)` returns

```
5*dy*x^3*y^4 + 3*dx*x^2*y^5
```

is there a way to have it return the differentials always at the end as in

```
5*x^3*y^4*dy + 3*x^2*y^5*dx
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find [differential forms](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/tensor/sage/tensor/differential_form_element.html) more useful here.  You'll note that you just have `dx` as a variable, which is ahead of both `x` and `y` in alphabetical order.

Comment: A similar answer is also given at http://ask.sagemath.org/question/25837/how-to-re-order-factors/